# Use tsc without npm install -g

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, tsc

I'm working on a project that I have to give to some guys.
The project is in typescript and so they have to run the command `tsc` to compile.

The problem is when I run this command after doing `npm install typescript` it seem that the command doesn't exist but if I install with the -g option then it works.

But I really would like the possibility to the futur owner of the project to just have to run npm install without installing dependencies on his computer.

But is it even possible ?

btw I'm on ubuntu 20

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm install typescript` installs it *locally to the project*. I would go further and add `--save-dev` so it only gets listed under `devDependencies`, not `dependencies`.

You can still run TypeScript in that situation. Your best bet is to add entries to the `"scripts"` key in `package.json`, like this:

```json
{
    "name": "blah",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "...",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc command arguments go here"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "...",
    "license": "...",
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^4.5.5"
    }
}
```

Then you run that command via:

```
npm run build
```

Node.js will find `tsc` in `node_modules` and run it.

Comment: it does the trick so it will solve the problem, do you know (for my tech culture) if there is a flag in the package.json to take command from node_module in priority instead of the /bin ?

Comment: @Saren I don't think that would be possible, as bas/zsh etc. don't care about package.json.

Comment: @Saren - As Nick said, I don't think so. In any given terminal / command prompt instance you can always change the path to include `node_modules`, but frankly I don't think that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

They can run it from the node_modules folder too.

```
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
```

Or if you don't like that you could use `npx` which runs binaries from local `node_modules` folder.

```
npx tsc
```

Comment: Bit of a pain, though. :-)

Comment: yes I agree but its valid;)

Comment: Don’t we have an option in the package to use command from the node_module ? (And without writting npm run…)

Comment: @Saren I added an option using `npx`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dependencies installed via a `package.json` and you have `yarn` installed you can run `yarn tsc`